# Docker + Ubuntu +Laravelでの開発でPHPのバージョンを変更したい

Tags: php, ubuntu, docker, laravel

現在Laravel sailでのWebアプリの開発に挑戦しています。
環境はDocker + Ubuntuで行っておりますが、借りているレンタルサーバーの対応PHPバージョンと合わないため、PHPのバージョンを下げて開発したいと思っています。

**現在のバージョン**

PHP 8.1.7
Laravel Framework 9.27.0
docker 20.10.16
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS \n \l

#### 現状

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example | bash
```

でlaravel sailをダウンロードすると上記のバージョンで構築されます。

#### やってみたこと

docker-compose.yml内の

```
context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
image: sail-8.1/app
```

を

```
context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
image: sail-8.0/app
```

に書き直し、

```
./vendor/bin/sail build --no-cache
./vendor/bin/sail up -d
```

でコンテナを立ち上げましたが、localhostに接続すると

> このページは動作していません localhost からデータが送信されませんでした。 ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

となり表示できません。

できれば、Laravelのバージョンも6.Xにできると嬉しいのですが...

学習始めたばかりで理解が薄い為、分かりづらい質問になっていたら申し訳ありません。
ご教授いただきたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

Ubuntuにphpのバージョンを複数インストールし、update-alternativesで切り替えることでできました。

ありがとうございました。